# EmberJS email client example incomplete?

Tags: ember.js

I'm just getting started with EmberJS and saw the "routing" example on the emberjs.com page.  It takes the form of a mail client.

I've downloaded all the files (app.js, application.hbs, etc) but can't figure out how to get it to "work".

There seems to be missing an HTML as the entry point?

OR, if nothing is missing, how do I view this app within a browser?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, although this example makes its point (showing how you don't need a lot of code to do something that is traditionally complicated), you can't use the files directly without some tooling to compile the templates, for instance.

It is recommended for any new Ember project to use Ember CLI to do this work for you. You should check out the ['Getting Started'-section of their website](http://www.ember-cli.com/#getting-started), and then read through the [section on using modules and the resolver](http://www.ember-cli.com/#using-modules), which will explain the ways in which the example you are looking at would be different.

The [official Ember Guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/) are very good for getting started, and I'd recommend you check that out (make sure you read that modules-part if you're using ember-cli (which you should) before you go through the guides). Also, please join us on IRC on #emberjs if you have any questions that would need some more back and forth.

Welcome!